# Non-null type in nullable references

Tags: kotlin

I have a class for binding a viewholder

```
class ViewHolderBinder(val onBind: (ViewHolder) -> Unit, val onClick: () -> Unit)
```

There is a list of these items in presenter

```
val items: MutableList<ViewHolderBinder> = mutableListOf()
```

ViewHolderBinder contains 2 non-null functions, but this call causes compile-time error

```
items.getOrNull(position)?.onClick()
```

However this call compiles as expected

```
items.getOrNull(position)?.let { it.onClick() }
```

Maybe i have missed something, but 2 these constructions are fully equivalent and i prefer to use first one, but it is not compiling.
I am using kotlin 1.3.10

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: @JBNizet http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/07/0019/3882/1294122/22/b477eee345.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Here's the actual error message you're getting:

`Reference has a nullable type '(() -> Unit)?', use explicit '?.invoke()' to make a function-like call instead`

Suppose you had this code:

```
val binder: ViewHolderBinder? = getBinder()
binder?.onClick()
```

`onClick()` is not a function you can invoke on the `ViewHolderBinder` instance. It's a *property* that holds a callback object. The full syntax to invoke that callback's function is

```
binder?.onClick?.invoke()
```

Kotlin also offers a special shorthand syntax that would work on a non-nullable `binder`:

```
binder.onClick()
```

If you apply it to a nullable binder,

```
binder?.onClick()
```

it expands to

```
binder?.onClick.invoke()
```

The type of the expression `binder?.onClick` is `(() -> Unit)?`, just like the error says. You aren't allowed to apply the `.` operator to a nullable type.

Comment: But everything that is executed after (?) is expected as a non-null, so why it is still nullable if it is defined as non-null in class declaration?

Comment: You probably misunderstand the semantics of the `?.` operator. Its result is the same as `.` in case the left-hand operand is non-null, and otherwise it is `null`. I hope this clears it up.